# Why are the x and y axes not colored black after applying the matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, manim

I work with Manim to visualize linear transformations. After applying a matrix to my coordinate system, I want to color the x and y axes black. However, the color of the axes remains unchanged. Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    LinearTransformationScene.__init__(
        self,
        show_coordinates=False,
        leave_ghost_vectors=False,
        show_basis_vectors=False,
        *kwargs
    )
def construct(self):
    self.camera.background_color = WHITE
    Mobject.set_default(color=BLACK)
    MyTexTemplate = TexTemplate(
        tex_compiler="xelatex",
        output_format=".xdv",
    )

matrix = np.array([[2, -1], [0, 1]])
self.apply_matrix(matrix)
```

I updated manimce to v0.18.0 and restarted everything.

How can I ensure that the x and y axes are displayed in black after applying this matrix? Are there any specific properties or methods I should use to affect the color of the axes? Many thanks for your help!

[image: current status]
[image: How it should look like.]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
self.play(ApplyMatrix(matrix, NumberPlane()))
```

Instead of:

```
self.apply_matrix(matrix)
```